# Creation of Views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, view

I am creating below view in sql server

```
create view View_CAM
as
SELECT
'5' FUNCTION,
getdate() UPLOAD_DATE,
'U' STATUS,
NULL INITIATED_DATE,
NULL PROCESSED_DATE,
NULL FINACLE_CUST_ID,
NULL PROCESSING_USER_ID,
**select currency from table_name** CURRENCIES
```

For CURRENCIES column i have to frame select query for data to be displayed.Above one is wrong.how it can be achieved.Thanks in advance

Comment: well, search how to perform joins

Comment: @Lamak dont think the OP needs any join here :)

Comment: @M.Ali If s/he doesn't, then this shouldn't even be a question

Comment: Is that where you draw a line? No join no question :)

Comment: @M.Ali sigh. If the user doesn't even know how to perform a single `SELECT`, then s/he should look into it before asking

Comment: @Lamak true agreed, I was just messing with ya mate :)

Comment: Sorry all i got answer for dis..                                                                                    create view View_CAM
as
SELECT
'5' FUNCTION,
getdate() UPLOAD_DATE,
'U' STATUS,
NULL INITIATED_DATE,
NULL PROCESSED_DATE,
NULL FINACLE_CUST_ID,
NULL PROCESSING_USER_ID,
(select currency from table_name) CURRENCIES ,A.ticket from tablename A

Answer (score -1):

```
create view View_CAM
as
SELECT  '5'         AS [FUNCTION]
       ,GETDATE()   AS UPLOAD_DATE
       ,'U'         AS [STATUS]
       ,NULL        AS INITIATED_DATE
       ,NULL        AS PROCESSED_DATE
       ,NULL        AS FINACLE_CUST_ID
       ,NULL        AS PROCESSING_USER_ID
       ,currency    AS CURRENCIES
from table_name
```

Comment: Sorry all i got answer for dis..                                                                                    create view View_CAM
as
SELECT
'5' FUNCTION,
getdate() UPLOAD_DATE,
'U' STATUS,
NULL INITIATED_DATE,
NULL PROCESSED_DATE,
NULL FINACLE_CUST_ID,
NULL PROCESSING_USER_ID,
(select currency from table_name) CURRENCIES from tablename